# Passing android.content.Context to a suspended function causes android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a suspended function that makes a network call to get some data and returns it. I am using Volley.

```
class PokeClient {
suspend fun getPokemonData(pokemonName: String, context: Context) = suspendCoroutine<Pokemon> { cont ->
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val request = url.plus(pokemonName)
    // some skipped code here
}
```

I am calling it in my activity like this:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        val pokeResult = pokeClient.getPokemonData(nameToSearch, applicationContext)
        pokemonList.add(pokeResult)
        pokemonAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pokemonList.size - 1)
    }
```

And I get an error like: **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

I suspect it may be because I am passing the context from the MainActivity and that is not correct. What is the alternative here?

Thanks,

Android Newbie

UPDATE:

[image]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val pokeClient = PokeClient()
    var pokemonList = mutableListOf<Pokemon>()

    val pokemonAdapter = PokemonRvAdapter(pokemonList)
    val pokemonRv = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_pokemon)
    pokemonRv.adapter = pokemonAdapter
    pokemonRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    val searchButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.search_btn)
    searchButton.setOnClickListener {
        val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Loading poke data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        toast.show()

        val nameToSearch = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.search_pokemon_txt).text.toString().lowercase()

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val pokeResult = pokeClient.getPokemonData(nameToSearch, applicationContext)
            pokemonList.add(pokeResult)
            pokemonAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pokemonList.size - 1)
        }
    }
}
}
```

PokeClient:

```
const val url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"

class PokeClient {
suspend fun getPokemonData(pokemonName: String, context: Context) = suspendCoroutine<Pokemon> { cont ->
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val request = url.plus(pokemonName)

        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, request, Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            val jObj = JSONObject(response)
            val imgUrl = jObj
                .getJSONObject("sprites")
                .getJSONObject("other")
                .getJSONObject("official-artwork")
                .getString("front_default")

            val inputStream = URL(imgUrl).openStream()
            /* call continuation.resume and pass your object */
            cont.resume(Pokemon(name = jObj.getString("name"), image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)))
        }, Response.ErrorListener { err ->
            cont.resumeWithException(err)
        })

        queue.add(stringRequest)
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you moving the work to a background thread? You have no references to something like `Dispatchers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Default`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

as per `CommonsWare` comment it seems `Dispatchers.IO` is what you are missing here. To be precise, it should look like this:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val pokeResult = pokeClient.getPokemonData(nameToSearch, applicationContext)
    pokemonList.add(pokeResult)
    pokemonAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pokemonList.size - 1)
}
```

or

```
   GlobalScope.launch {

      withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      val pokeResult = pokeClient.getPokemonData(nameToSearch, applicationContext)
      pokemonList.add(pokeResult)
      pokemonAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pokemonList.size - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Good point, unfortunately adding Dispatchers.IO did not fix my error :/

Comment: what's issue you're facing? describe it a bit maybe we can fix it :)

Comment: Updated question

Comment: can you also show how are you using the result from the `getPokemonData()` method in your `View`?

Comment: Added whole activity

Comment: can you add complete code for the `PokeClient()` as well?

Comment: Posted PokeClient.kt

Answer (score 0):

Through I am completely null about kotlin but as far as I am concerned this error happens when you **perform internet related action (Ex, Load Data from a site) on main thread** or you haven't declared **internet permission in manifest** file. Instead you should create new thread and perform the action there. If you don't mind adding java code here is a snippet

```
  class getData implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Do work over here such as loading date from url

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    //To update ui put code inside here

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And in the main method use this:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(new getData());//use class name
        thread.start();//To start execution
```